# Can't find c++ header files and MacOSX12.1.SDK through CMake in Clion macOS. But Xcode is working

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, clion

I'm in macOS Monterey 12.3.
When I try to load my CMAKE file on CLion. I got this error, it says that it can not find the MacOSX12.1.SDK. But my current version is in 12.3. I'm not sure why it goes to the 12.1 version rather than 12.3.

```
CMake Warning at /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/Platform/Darwin-Initialize.cmake:303 (message):
Ignoring CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT value:
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk"
because the directory does not exist.
```

And the warning like this:

```
CMake Error in Build/Debug/_deps/glew-src/CMakeLists.txt:
Imported target "OpenGL::GLU" includes non-existent path 
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework"
  in its INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.  Possible reasons include:

  * The path was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and references files it does not
  provide.
```

In the meanwhile, when I try to compile my program, I got multiple clang errors show like this `include path for libstdc++ headers not found; pass '-stdlib=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Werror,-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]`

For this part, I tried the method first remove the current version of commandLineTools and do `Xcode-select --install` to fix it. But after I done that, these bugs were still there:(

I'm not sure what I have done to my Mac, It just suddenly become like this.

Comment: At a guess you've previously run cmake with an older SDK and the path has been cached. Clear the cache (easiest just to delete your build directory) and re-run cmake

Comment: I confirm @AlanBirtles hint works.

Comment: Thank you @AlanBirtles — it works now!! 
I wish I'd seen this two hours ago before I updated a dozen irrelevant things

Answer (score 0):

Cmake has cached an old sdk path which no longer exists after upgrading Xcode.

You need to clear the camke cache, the easiest way to do this is to simply delete the build directory.